# Xcode including rogue files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I am currently making an application and have an issue selecting data from an sqlite database. Although this is currently a problem I am enquiring about something else.

On investigating why the I could not select data I was reviewing the files that are on my iphone for the application to ensure the database file did in fact exist however what I have found is that another sqlite file also exists.

I recognise the name of the file as it is a file that I have created in a different project.

I have tried to search for the filename to ensure I have not copied code causing it and I cannot locate that file name in my code at all.

Does anyone know why this file may have appeared in this project?

----- UPDATE -----

Since originally posting this I have come up with a couple of thoughts. iCloud was originally turned on. I have turned this off. I originally copied and pasted code that referenced the other database. I have tried to delete the file but this fails. I have also deleted the app from the iPhone and have found that the folder for the app remains but claims it is empty and has 0 bytes contained within it (the rogue DB is 116 KB). I think this might be related to the iCloud issue. I am going to restore the content and settings as a test.

----- Update ------

After resetting content and settings the file still comes back so unsure what is going on at present.

Comment: upvoted for the use of the phrase "rogue files." Made me smile...

Answer (score 0):

Goto the Target's Build Phase tab and look in the Copy Bundle Resources section. Most likely, the other sqlite file is in there and being distributed/installed as part of the package.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have checked the list as suggested but it is not contained there either. I am going to install the app on a friends phone to see if it can be replicated.